# Redirect grep output to file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am not sure as to why that redirection provided in the code does not work. Every time I run the script, the output file is always empty. Does anyone have an idea on that?

Thanks.

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK_FOR="DefaultProblem"
FILES=`ls plugins/*source*.jar`

for i in $FILES
  do
    # echo "Looking in $i ..."
    unzip -p $i | grep -i $LOOK_FOR > output #> /dev/null 
    if [ $? == 0 ]
    then
      echo ">>>> Found $LOOK_FOR in $i <<<<"
    fi
  done
```

Comment: For future reference, "does not work" is not a good description. Tell us *how* it doesn't work.

Comment: It's likely to be *very* relevant to any future questions you might have -- assuming you take my advice to heart.  I didn't say something relevant to the problem because it had already been answered.  This is what comments are for.  I really am trying to help you here.  Please consider the possibility that I might have a valid point.

Comment: @fabricemarcelin: posting a comment *is* participating in the discussion

Comment: @KeithThompson I have updated the question and explain the problem.

Comment: In addition to Keith Thompson's comments (and for the benefit of future readers), you can run your script with `bash -x ./scriptName.sh` (see http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/debugging-shell-script.html), which will show you the execution of your script line by line. Google _debug <shellname> <scriptname>_ for other shells. This will help you get a better idea of why your script is failing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You may want to use `>>` (append) instead of `>` (overwrite) for redirection as:

```
unzip -p $i | grep -iF "$LOOK_FOR" >> output
```

Since you're executing this command in a loop and overwriting file `output` every time, it **might be blank in the end** if very last command with grep doesn't find any matching line in unzip output.

Comment: Awesome, it works like a charm. I totally didn't think about that. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You have three problems

1. Don't try to parse the output of `ls`. Instead just use `for i in plugins/*source*.jar` The major reason is that your script will completely and utterly break on any files that have spaces in their names. See [this link](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) for a litany of reasons why not to parse `ls`
2. You need to use `>>` instead of `>` as the latter will overwrite the output file on each iteration of the loop. The former will *append* to it
3. Use more quotes! You'll want to quote your variables to make sure they aren't subjected to word splitting

Also, you can inline the `if` test.  So putting it all together we have:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK_FOR="DefaultProblem"
for i in plugins/*source*.jar
do
    # echo "Looking in $i ..."
    if unzip -p "$i" | grep -i "$LOOK_FOR" >> output #> /dev/null
    then
      echo ">>>> Found $LOOK_FOR in $i <<<<"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: Since this is searching multiple files but doing so one at a time, the `grep` output as shown won't contain a file name identifying which file each line came from.  Sometimes you can fix that by adding `/dev/null` to the `grep` command line; unfortunately, this is not one of those occasions.  You'd need to add: `| sed "s%^%$i:%"` before the `>>` redirection.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Good idea but in this case I would suggest just using the `-l` flag to `grep`

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect the output of the entire loop:

```
#!/bin/sh

LOOK_FOR="DefaultProblem"
FILES=`ls plugins/*source*.jar`

for i in $FILES ; do
    # echo "Looking in $i ..." 1>&2
    unzip -p $i | grep -i $LOOK_FOR
    if [ $? == 0 ] ; then
        echo ">>>> Found $LOOK_FOR in $i <<<<" 1>&2
    fi
done > output
```

Note that I've redirected the diagnostic messages to stderr.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a `for loop` and an `if conditional` you can do everything in one `find` command

```
find /path/to/plugins -name "*source*.jar" -exec sh -c 'unzip -l "{}" | grep -q DefaultProblem' \; -print
```

Comment: Even using the output of `find` will also break with files that have spaces in their name.  The way to fix this is via the `-print0` flag to `find` and a `while IFS= -r -d '' line` loop with bash using process substitution. Or better yet use Bash 4's globstar

Comment: True … Your answer really covers all the potential issues. Ill go ahead and delete mine. :)

Comment: @SiegeX Have modified the answer to offer something new.

Comment: If that works, its definitely not portable.  Instead, you'll want to pass `{}` as an argument to the shell.  `find /path/to/plugins -name "*source*.jar" -exec sh -c 'for f; do unzip -l "$f" | grep -q DefaultProblem; done' _ {} \; -print`. The underscore is a throw away argument, it's needed because the first parameter to the shell is the name

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX. I'll leave that for the OP to try out with this data. But thanks for the feed back. That's good stuff. I thought 3 months would be good enough to learn Bash, awk and sed, and it's been 4 months and counting. :)

Comment: It's the standard 80/20 rule. For just 4 months, you have certainly come a long way.

Comment: Thanks @SiegeX for your kind words. Time to dive into the `bash` manual. Sometimes I feel that had I started off as a Developer than a Tester life would have been so much better. :)

Comment: Sticking around here and even more so #bash, #awk, #sed on freenode will accelerate that learning quite a bit.

Comment: True on both counts. I really like [lynda.com](http://www.lynda.com/) video training courses since I tend to get lost in books. Just completed [Perl Essentials 5 by Bill Weinman](http://www.lynda.com/Perl-5-tutorials/essential-training/61025-2.html) over the weekend. Overloaded with all the information right now. :)

Comment: Perl is something I've always had on my todo list but never got to.  I think python may have bumped perl for that spot, though

Comment: Yea since I don't know any of those (Perl, Python and Ruby) I though I will go thru all three and decide. :) I am really liking Ruby. For the time being I am seeing weird activity on my SO account. I just lost 2000 points and now getting some back. Weird.